# Is it possible to make a program that goes into continuous Uninterruptible Sleep and is non-killable?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, scheduling

According to my knowledge processes in Uninterruptible Sleep cannot be killed. So I thought - Is it possible to make a program that goes into that state and stays in it without going through other states? It would "run" in the system as long as its running.

Comment: What is your initial problem to solve ? Please read [What is the XY-Problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: There is no problem. **It's question about possibility**. If you believe that this type of question should not be included in this site, I would gladly remove it and ask somewhere else

Comment: No, I guess it's fine then. Just wanted to make sure ;-)

Comment: It probably is possible -- by exploiting kernel bugs. With fuse filesystems, it may be possible even by exploiting bugs in the userland code of those filesystems. But don't take my word for the latter -- I'm just guessing, not really sure if it's possible ;-)

Comment: Accessing a file on a hard-mounted NFS  filesystem when the server is down should accomplish that. EDIT: I just read that a SIGKILL can kill the process that waits for NFS IO.

Comment: @berndbausch could you share where you read that?

Comment: @berndbausch I wish - I could never get any process stuck on NFS to die short of rebooting the system

Comment: I love [tag:stupid-question] — one of those tags that needs a setting saying that only the post author can apply it ;-).

Comment: @StephenKitt The nfs(5) man page: "The intr / nointr mount option is deprecated after kernel 2.6.25. Only SIGKILL can interrupt a pending NFS operation on these kernels".